# How to click a button based on ref attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jquery can click based on class and id attributes but can click be invoked based on ref attribute ?

I've based below code on `ref="btFirst"`, but unsure how to access `ref`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DfUy/297/) src:

```
<button class="ag-paging-button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')" ref="btFirst" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">First</button>

$( ".btFirst" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS attribute selector (nice and thorough CSS Tricks [reference](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/)):

```js
$('[ref="btFirst"]').on("click", function(e) {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button ref="btFirst">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('button[ref="btFirst"]').on('click', function(e){
 alert('ref button clicked');
});
```

```js
$('button[ref="btFirst"]').on('click', function(e){
 alert('ref button clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="ag-paging-button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')" ref="btFirst" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">First</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more specific:

**Html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="ag-paging-button" ref="btFirst" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">First</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "button.ag-paging-button[ref='btFirst']" ).on('click', function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
});
```

You dont need to add `onclick="alert('Hello world!')"` in button tag

Hope this may help you.